# Como procesar un meta_value de wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

estaría muy agradecido de su ayuda y orientación.

Tengo una funcion PHP para solicitar mediante AJAX una fila específica en **Wordpress**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_mark_message_as_read', 'mark_message_as_read');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_mark_message_as_read', 'mark_message_as_read');

function mark_message_as_read() {
    global $wpdb;   
    $rango_precios = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE post_id = 45 AND meta_key = '_wc_price_calculator_pricing_rules'");
    
    wp_send_json_success([$rango_precios[0]]);
    wp_send_json_error([/* some data here */]);
}
```

La función Ajax es la siguiente

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#btn_prueba').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: {
                    action: 'mark_message_as_read',
                },
                success: function (output) {
                    if(output.success == true){
                        console.log(output.data[0]['meta_value'])
                    }
                }
            });
        })
        
    })
</script>
```

Dicha salida me devuelve lo siguiente, de que manera puedo obtener todos los range start y range_end , para despues poder comparar dichos valores contra un input ?

```
[
    {
        "meta_id": "345",
        "post_id": "45",
        "meta_key": "_wc_price_calculator_pricing_rules",
        "meta_value": "a:9:{i:0;a:5:{s:11:\"range_start\";s:3:\"400\";s:9:\"range_end\";s:4:\"1599\";s:5:\"price\";s:4:\"15.6\";s:13:\"regular_price\";s:4:\"15.6\";s:10:\"sale_price\";s:0:\"\";}i:1;a:5:{s:11:\"range_start\";s:4:\"1600\";s:9:\"range_end\";s:4:\"2499\";s:5:\"price\";s:4:\"10.6\";s:13:\"regular_price\";s:4:\"10.6\";s:10:\"sale_price\";s:0:\"\";}i:2;a:5:{s:11:\"range_start\";s:4:\"2500\";s:9:\"range_end\";s:4:\"3599\";s:5:\"price\";s:3:\"8.5\";s:13:\"regular_price\";s:3:\"8.5\";s:10:\"sale_price\";s:0:\"\";}i:3;a:5:{s:11:\"range_start\";s:4:\"3600\";s:9:\"range_end\";s:4:\"4899\";s:5:\"price\";s:3:\"7.2\";s:13:\"regular_price\";s:3:\"7.2\";s:10:\"sale_price\";s:0:\"\";}i:4;a:5:{s:11:\"range_start\";s:4:\"4900\";s:9:\"range_end\";s:4:\"6399\";s:5:\"price\";s:3:\"6.4\";s:13:\"regular_price\";s:3:\"6.4\";s:10:\"sale_price\";s:0:\"\";}i:5;a:5:{s:11:\"range_start\";s:4:\"6400\";s:9:\"range_end\";s:4:\"8099\";s:5:\"price\";s:3:\"5.8\";s:13:\"regular_price\";s:3:\"5.8\";s:10:\"sale_price\";s:0:\"\";}i:6;a:5:{s:11:\"range_start\";s:4:\"8100\";s:9:\"range_end\";s:4:\"9999\";s:5:\"price\";s:3:\"5.4\";s:13:\"regular_price\";s:3:\"5.4\";s:10:\"sale_price\";s:0:\"\";}i:7;a:5:{s:11:\"range_start\";s:5:\"10000\";s:9:\"range_end\";s:0:\"\";s:5:\"price\";s:4:\"5.01\";s:13:\"regular_price\";s:4:\"5.01\";s:10:\"sale_price\";s:0:\"\";}i:8;a:5:{s:11:\"range_start\";s:1:\"0\";s:9:\"range_end\";s:3:\"399\";s:5:\"price\";s:2:\"16\";s:13:\"regular_price\";s:2:\"16\";s:10:\"sale_price\";s:0:\"\";}}"
    }
]
```

Comment: Esto `a:9:{i:0;a:5:{s:1 ...}`  no es un JSON válido. Además, si sólo quieres devolver un elemento, ¿por qué no pones un `LIMIT 1` a tu consulta SQL?  Además, no sé por que lo pones como array para devolverlo. Intenta así: `wp_send_json_success($rango_precios[0]);` En el cliente, haz un `console.log(data);` sin más y dinos qué muestra. Puedes copiar ese resultado y validarlo [aquí](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#). Es claro que mientras no haya un JSON válido no podrás trabajar con él.

Comment: Edite la pregunta, ahi eh dejado un print de la salida que genera el console.log(output.data), y si la consulta esta limitada a solo mostrar un id especifico, por lo que la consulta SQL solo esta devolviendo 1 fila

Comment: Biennnn, eso sí es un JSON válido. Dinos ahora qué es lo que quieres hacer exactamente con el valor que hay en la propiedad `meta_value`.

Comment: Tengo un input donde ingreso un dato numérico, que va desde el 0 al 10000; en la propiedad meta_value hay distintos range_start-range_end-regular_price, lo que quiero conseguir es que cuando se ingrese un valor en el input, este sea comparado con los rangos, entonces si dicho valor se encuentra entre ese rango muestre un precio u otro

Comment: Me pregunto por qué no filtras directamente en la consulta SQL ¿?

Comment: por que todos esos rangos se almacenan en un solo campo que es meta_value, todo esta metido ahi, asi almacena el plugin los datos

Comment: Pues me parece harto complicado y costoso buscar un dato entre un montón de datos cuando se podría normalizar, de modo que vayas a buscar el dato exacto. Debe haber una mejor forma de hacerlo, pero como trabajo con meta values de Wordpress no podría hablarte con más propiedad del tema.

Comment: Investiga algún approach parecido a [este (revisa los dos enlaces finales a la doc de Wordpress)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/392900) que te permita consultar los meta values por rango o algo así, debe existir, pues no es lógico tener que estar buscando una aguja a ciegas en un pajar.

Comment: Una duda, porque no solo llamar la función get post meta, get_post_meta( 45, '_wc_price_calculator_pricing_rules', true )

Entonces puedes hacer algo como echo json_encode( get_post_meta( 45, '_wc_price_calculator_pricing_rules', true ) ); lo cual devolvería un JSON Válido si no me equivoco. Luego cada vez que se agrega un valor a un input detectas con onChange y revisas si dentro del JSON dicho valor existe usando forEach() para recorrerlos

Comment: muchas gracias estimado, eso me sirvio de maravilla